# UIView with CollectionView and TableView in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a UiView that contains a CollectionView for images of a kind of products and a TableView that contains cells with images and labels of another kind of products.
What I'm trying to do is give this UIView a scroll, showing of the images of the first CollectionView unfolded, and scrolling down show all the TableViewCells unfolded, not with his own scroll in their section.
I have tried embedding the two sections into a scrollView but this doesn't worked.
What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you picked a UIView instead of a UIScrollView? Seems like a scrollview would solve your problem.